# How do I configure Eclipse/PyDev to properly allow references to command line tools?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm trying to debug a python script inside of Eclipse/PyDev, but I can't seem to get the script to execute properly when run from inside the dev environment.

It appears that the Eclipse/PyDev environment restricts access to command line tools for programs that are in the process of being debugged.

How do I get around this restriction? Is there a way to, maybe, add a reference to the relevant command line tools in the Eclipse project?

*Updated*:

This is the chunk of code that attempts to run an external app. Could the issue be related to the child-thread in there?

```
def call_command_in_dir_unix(app, args, targetdir):
    # this is the unix implementation
    (r,w) = os.pipe()
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid == -1:
      return 'could not fork'
    if pid == 0:
      # child
      print "child!"
      os.close(r)
      os.dup2(os.open("/dev/null", os.O_WRONLY), 0)
      os.dup2(w, 1)
      os.dup2(w, 2)
      os.chdir(targetdir)
      os.environ['openin_any'] = 'p'
      os.environ['openout_any'] = 'p'
      os.environ['shell_escape'] = 'f'
      import resource
      resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CPU,
                         (MAX_RUN_TIME * 1000, MAX_RUN_TIME * 1000)) # docs say this is seconds, but it is msecs on my system.
      # os.execvp will raise an exception if the executable isn't
      # present. [[ try os.execvp("aoeu", ['aoeu'])  ]]
      # If we don't catch exceptions here, it will be caught at the
      # main body below, and then os.rmdir(tmpdir) will be called
      # twice, once for each fork.  The second one raises an exception
      # in the main code, which gets back to the user.  This is bad.
      try:
        os.execvp(app, [app] + list(args))
      finally:
        print "failed to exec()",app
        os._exit(2)
    else:
      # parent
      os.close(w)
      r = os.fdopen(r,"r")
      output = ''.join(r.readlines())
      (npid, exi) = os.waitpid(pid, 0)
      r.close()
      sig = exi & 0xFF
      stat = exi >> 8
      if stat != 0 or sig != 0:
        return ' error! exitcode was %d (signal %d), transscript follows:\n\n%s' % (stat,sig,output)
      return None
    # notreached
```

Comment: It appears that the Eclipse/PyDev environment restricts access to command line tools for programs that are in the process of being debugged. <--- what makes you think so?

Comment: The script is having problems finding the command line tools it's relying on. Maybe it's just an issue of setting a path variable somewhere?

Comment: What actual errors are you seeing?  Eclipse/PyDev does do things to at least partially segregate the environment things are running on from the configuration of the wider system, but it shouldn't actually restrict you from running anything.

Comment: It's most likely issue relatedd to @blueberryfields own code, one must share the code and error message to have input for error solving.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the subprocess module? It handles all this stuff for you.

Comment: What I'd do to debug that is print my os.environ to see if it matches what you're expecting (by default it should inherit the environment from the shell where eclipse was started, but you can also configure that in the launch config).